# Google Maps and Fusion Tables - Get result in Popup Window that will be display the Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have problems to improve the code (I do not know if this can be done). I do the map base on geocodezip example http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test//v3_FusionTables_CountryBrowser_encryptedID.html , and now I want to when I click on attribute value (polygon name) inside the sidebar to get result in Popup Window that will display the Map (with polygon that I previously click inside the sidebar); like at JavaScript Window Open example http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptpopups.php. I have not done anything with the code because I do not know where to start, code that I use is below. Does anyone have any suggestions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>USA7</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body, #map_canvas {
    width:   750px;
    height:  600px;
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
}
    .infowindow * {font-size: 90%; margin: 0}
.style1 {color: #FFFFFF}
</style>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
// globals
var map = null;
var infoWindow = null;
var geoXml = null;
var geoXmlDoc = null;
var myLatLng = null;
var myOptions = null;
var mapCenter = null;
var geocodeTheCountry = true;
var gpolygons = [];
var geocoder = null;

// Fusion Table data ID
var FT_TableID = '1GoqHJ9E9Ff_rfl_CLTGNlgXF3ssEaywN4_lVNUA'; // original '1-bZhRr6OMbj4NWZcY8XnVjpijvV97yNgSXSf_mE';
var CountryName = "USA"; // "United States of America";

  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']});

function  createSidebar() {
  // set the query using the parameters
document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = "querying for data";
var FT_Query2 = "SELECT 'STATEFP', 'name', 'geometry' FROM "+FT_TableID+" WHERE 'STATEFP' = '"+CountryName+"' ORDER by 'name'";
document.getElementById("FTquery2").innerHTML = FT_Query2; 
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent(FT_Query2);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

  //set the callback function
  query.send(getData);
}

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(createSidebar);

function getCountryNames() {
  // set the query using the parameters
var FT_Query_CountryName = "SELECT 'STATEFP', count() FROM "+FT_TableID+" GROUP by 'STATEFP' ORDER by 'STATEFP'";
document.getElementById("FTquery4").innerHTML = FT_Query_CountryName; 
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent(FT_Query_CountryName);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

  //set the callback function
  query.send(createCountryDropdown);
}

function createCountryDropdown(response) {
if (!response) {
  alert('no response');
  return;
}
if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
} 
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();

  var countryNames = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    var countryName = response.getDataTable().getValue(i,0);
    // countryName = countryName.substring(0,countryName.indexOf('('));
    countryNames[countryName] = countryName;
  }
  var countryNameDropdown = "<select name='country_select' onchange='handleSelected(this)'>"
  countryNameDropdown += '<option selected> - Select a State by ID - <\/option>';
  for (countryName in countryNames) {
    countryNameDropdown += "<option value='"+countryName+"'>"+countryName+"</option>"
//    document.getElementById('country_list').innerHTML += countryName+"<br>";
  }
  countryNameDropdown += "</select>"
  document.getElementById('dropdown_menu').innerHTML = countryNameDropdown;
}

      // ======= This function handles selections from the select box ====
      function handleSelected(opt) {
        if (opt.selectedIndex > 0) {
          CountryName = geoXML3.nodeValue(opt[opt.selectedIndex]);
          DisplayCountry();
        } else { 
          alert("Please pick a country");
        }
      }

function DisplayCountry() {
      // geocode the country
      var addressStr = CountryName;
      if (addressStr != "Baikonur Cosmodrome") addressStr += " Country";
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressStr}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
   FT_Query = "SELECT 'geometry' FROM "+FT_TableID+" WHERE 'STATEFP' = '"+CountryName+"';";
   gpolygons = [];
   layer.setQuery({select:'geometry',from:FT_TableID,where:"'STATEFP' = '"+CountryName+"'"});
   document.getElementById("FTquery").innerHTML = FT_Query; 
   createSidebar();
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var FTresponse = null;

      myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808,-122.0838851);
      // these set the initial center, zoom and maptype for the map 
      // if it is not specified in the query string
      var lat = 37.422104808;
      var lng = -122.0838851;
      var zoom = 18;
      var maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;

      // If there are any parameters at eh end of the URL, they will be in  location.search
      // looking something like  "?marker=3"

      // skip the first character, we are not interested in the "?"
      var query = location.search.substring(1);

      // split the rest at each "&" character to give a list of  "argname=value"  pairs
      var pairs = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
        // break each pair at the first "=" to obtain the argname and value
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1);
        if (argname == "country") {CountryName = unescape(value);}
    value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1).toLowerCase();

        // process each possible argname  -  use unescape() if theres any chance of spaces
    if (argname == "geocode") {geocodeTheCountry = (value != "false");}
        if (argname == "id") {id = unescape(value);}
        if (argname == "filename") {filename = unescape(value);}
        if (argname == "marker") {index = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "lat") {lat = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "lng") {lng = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "zoom") {
      zoom = parseInt(value);
      myGeoXml3Zoom = false;
    }
        if (argname == "type") {
// from the v3 documentation 8/24/2010
// HYBRID This map type displays a transparent layer of major streets on satellite images. 
// ROADMAP This map type displays a normal street map. 
// SATELLITE This map type displays satellite images. 
// TERRAIN This map type displays maps with physical features such as terrain and vegetation. 
          if (value == "m") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP;}
          if (value == "k") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE;}
          if (value == "h") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID;}
          if (value == "t") {maptype = google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN;}

        }
      }
      if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lng)) {
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      }
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



//define callback function, this is called when the results are returned
function getData(response) {
if (!response) {
  alert('no response');
  return;
}
if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
} 
  FTresponse = response;
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
  if (numRows <= 1) {
    document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = "no data";
    return;
  }

  //concatenate the results into a string, you can build a table here
  fusiontabledata = "<table><tr>";
//  for(i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
    fusiontabledata += "<th colspan='2'>" + response.getDataTable().getValue(1,0) + "</th>";
//   }
  fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";
  fusiontabledata += "<tr><td colspan='2' align='left'><a href='javascript:showAll();'>Display all polygons in selected State</a></td></tr>";
  for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
//    for(j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
   /*
   var kml =  response.getDataTable().getValue(i,2);
   geoXml.parseKmlString("<Placemark>"+kml+"</Placemark>");
   */    
      fusiontabledata += "<td><a href='javascript:myFTclick("+i+")'>"+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 1) + "</a></td><td><a href='javascript:zoomTo("+i+")'>show</a></td>";
//    }
    fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";
  }
  fusiontabledata += "</table>"  
  //display the results on the page
  document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = fusiontabledata;


}

function infoWindowContent(name, description, id) {
   content =   '<div class="FT_infowindow"><h3>' + name + 
               '</h3><div>' + description + '</div>';
   if (typeof id != "undefined") {
     content += '<a href="javascript:zoomTo('+id+');">zoom to</a>';
   }
   content += '</div>';
   return content;
}

function zoomTo(id) {
  loadRow(id);
  if (gpolygons[id] && gpolygons[id].bounds) {
    map.fitBounds(gpolygons[id].bounds);
    var queryStr = "SELECT 'geometry' FROM "+FT_TableID+" WHERE 'STATEFP' = '"+CountryName+"' AND 'name' = '"+gpolygons[id].name+"';"
    layer.setQuery({select:'geometry',from:FT_TableID,where:"'STATEFP' = '"+CountryName+"' AND 'name' = '"+gpolygons[id].name+"'"});    
    document.getElementById("FTquery3").innerHTML = queryStr; 
  }
}

function showAll() {
  layer.setQuery({select: 'geometry', from:FT_TableID, where:"'STATEFP' = '"+CountryName+"'"});
}

function loadRow(row) {
   if (!gpolygons[row]) {
     var name = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row,1);
     var kml =  FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row,2);
     // create a geoXml3 parser for the click handlers
     var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                    map: map,
            zoom: false,
                    infoWindow: infoWindow,
                    singleInfoWindow: true
                });

     geoXml.parseKmlString("<Placemark>"+kml+"</Placemark>");
     geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].setMap(null);
     gpolygons[row] = new Object();
     gpolygons[row].position = geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].bounds.getCenter();
     gpolygons[row].bounds = geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[0].bounds;
     gpolygons[row].name = name;
   }
}
function myFTclick(row) {
   var description = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row,0);
   var name = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row,1);
   loadRow(row);
   var position = gpolygons[row].position;

   // Set up and create the infowindow
   if (!infoWindow) infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
   infoWindow.setOptions({
      content: infoWindowContent(name, description, row),
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 2),
      position: position
    });
    // Infowindow-opening event handler
    infoWindow.open(map);
}

function initialize() {
  myOptions = {
               zoom: zoom,
               center: myLatLng,
               // zoom: 5,
               // center: myLatlng,
               mapTypeId: maptype
              };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                            myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
    infoWindow.close();
    var FT_click_query="SELECT 'STATEFP' FROM "+FT_TableID+" WHERE ST_INTERSECTS('geometry',CIRCLE(LATLNG"+event.latLng+", 1));";
    // alert(event.latLng+"query="+FT_click_query);
    // set the query using the parameters
    var queryText = encodeURIComponent(FT_click_query);
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);
document.getElementById("FTquery5").innerHTML = FT_click_query; 

    //set the callback function
    query.send(getCountryFromClick);
  });



  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  if (geocoder && geocodeTheCountry) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': CountryName+" Country"}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }

var FT_Query = "SELECT 'geometry' FROM "+FT_TableID+" WHERE 'STATEFP' = '"+CountryName+"';";
var FT_Options = { suppressInfoWindows: true, query: {from:FT_TableID, select: "geometry", where: "'STATEFP' = '"+CountryName+"'"}};
// https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col18+from+1-bZhRr6OMbj4NWZcY8XnVjpijvV97yNgSXSf_mE+where+col19+%3D+'USA'&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=34.56204535683132&lng=-86.65887199999997&t=1&z=9&l=col18&y=2&tmplt=2
document.getElementById("FTquery").innerHTML = FT_Query; 
  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(/*FT_TableID, */ FT_Options);
  layer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(event) {
    infoWindow.close();
    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent(event.row.name.value,event.row.STATEFP.value));
    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });

  getCountryNames();
}

  function getCountryFromClick(response) {
if (!response) {
  alert('no response');
  return;
}
if (response.isError()) {
  alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
  return;
} 
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
  if (numRows <= 1) {
    return;
  }

  CountryName = response.getDataTable().getValue(1, 0);
  // alert("CountryName="+CountryName);
  DisplayCountry();  

}    


</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr><td colspan="2"><h4>USA States ID<div id="dropdown_menu">
</div></h4></td></tr>
<tr>
 <td><div id="map_canvas" style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#333333"></div></td>
 <td><div id="sidebar" style="width:300px;height:600px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#333333; overflow:auto"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><span class="style1"><div id="FTquery"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><span class="style1"><div id="FTquery2"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><span class="style1"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><span class="style1"><div id="FTquery4"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><span class="style1"><div id="FTquery5"></div></td></tr>
</table>
<div id="country_list"></div>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Currently clicking on the sidebar does open an infowindow and display data.  Do you want to open a new window with another map containing just the polygon that was clicked? (like what happens on the main map when you click "show" in the sidebar)

Comment: Yes, I want to open a new window with another map that containing just the polygon that was clicked.

Comment: One option would be to make a map that takes a query string that causes it to display just that polygon, pass that URL to the new window.  Have you attempted that? If so, what problems did you encounter?  Or is that not what you are attempting to do?

Comment: Inside this code I do not know how to pass URL to the new window, do you mean to use IFrame?